# Prediction on Neural Network in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, nnet

I want to get the accuracy or the `RMSE` of the Prediction result of a neural network. I started using a Confusion Matrix, but as indicated by previous answers, the Confusion Matrix gives valid results for non Continuous variables.

Is there any way I can get the accuracy or the error rate of a Neural Network Prediction??

As an example here is the code I've got until now:

```
library(nnet)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
data(rock)
newformula <- perm ~ area + peri + shape
y <- rock[, "perm"]
x <- rock[!colnames(rock)%in% "perm"]
original <- datacol(rock,"perm")

nnclas_model <- nnet(newformula, data = rock, size = 4, decay = 0.0001, maxit = 500)    
nnclas_prediction <- predict(nnclas_model, x)
nnclas_tab <- table(nnclas_prediction, y)
rmse <- sqrt(mean((original - nnclas_prediction)^2))
```

Does anyone know how can I make this work? or how can I get the Accuracy or the of the Neural Network Prediction? 
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why not call `confusionMatrix` directly on the predicted results and `y`? i.e. `confusionMatrix(nnclas_prediction, y)`

Comment: It seems you're trying to create a confusion matrix for predictions about a continuous variable.  Confusion matrices are meant for classification problems...

Comment: you mean something like this: `nnclas_prediction <- confusionMatrix((predict(nnclas_model, x)),y)`?

Comment: No, I mean that `perm`, the left-hand variable in your formula, is continuous.   So making a confusion matrix for predictions about `perm` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see, is there any other way I can get the same information by using continuous variables? something like accuracy? or the only thing I can do is get the `RMSE`? Or is there a Kind of `Confusion Matrix`but for continuous variables??

Comment: Unless you're trying to treat the different levels of `perm` as different classes.  Is that what you want?

Comment: What I want is to get the accuracy or the `RMSE`of the Neural Network Prediction. I just edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, confusion matrices are for classification problems.  If you meant to classify `perm` according to its levels, then the following code should work for you.

```
library(nnet)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
data(rock)
rock$perm <- as.factor(rock$perm)
nnclas_model <- nnet(perm ~ area + peri + shape, data = rock, 
                     size = 4, decay = 0.0001, maxit = 500)
x <- rock[, 1:3]
y <- rock[, 4]
yhat <- predict(nnclas_model, x, type = 'class')
confusionMatrix(as.factor(yhat), y)
```

If you mean to treat `perm` as continuous, the confusion matrix doesn't make any sense.  You should think in terms of mean-squared error instead.

Comment: I've tried to get the `RMSE` but still i have no succes, I just can not see what I am doing wrong (please see my edited question)

Comment: @Jason in the last line of the code `confusionMatrix(as.factor(yhat), y)`, do you mean x instead of y, where is `y <- rock[, 4]`? Just not sure where that `y` is coming from.  Thanks!

Comment: @nate-m, yes, I had skipped a line.  I've added it now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "nnet", but I have used the "neuralnet" library and am able to get the RMSE. Here is my full code: **Just change the data for training_Data and testing_Data as per your requirements and in place of "Channel" give what is your classification attribute**

```
  dat <- read.csv("Give path of your data file here")
summary(dat)
cleandata <- dat
cleandata <- na.omit(cleandata)

#scaling

apply(cleandata,MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x)sum(is.na(x)))
maxs    =   apply(cleandata,    MARGIN  =   2,  max)
mins    =   apply(cleandata,    MARGIN  =   2,  min)
scaledData =     as.data.frame(scale(cleandata, center  =   mins,   scale   =   maxs    - mins))
summary(scaledData)

#Splitting data in 80:20 ratio
train = sample(1:nrow(scaledData), nrow(scaledData)*0.8)
test = -train
training_Data = scaledData[train,]
testing_Data = scaledData[test,]
dim(training_Data)
dim(testing_Data)

#neural net

library(neuralnet)
n   <- names(training_Data)
f   <- as.formula(paste("Channel    ~", paste(n[!n  %in%    "Channel"], collapse    =   "   +   ")))
neuralnet_Model <- neuralnet(f,data = training_Data, hidden = c(2,1))
plot(neuralnet_Model)
neuralnet_Model$result.matrix
pred_neuralnet<-compute(neuralnet_Model,testing_Data[,2:8])
pred_neuralnet.scaled   <- pred_neuralnet$net.result *(max(scaledData$Channel)-min(scaledData$Channel))+min(scaledData$Channel)
real.values <- (testing_Data$Channel)*(max(cleandata$Channel)-min(cleandata$Channel))+min(cleandata$Channel)
MSE.neuralnetModel  <- sum((real.values - pred_neuralnet.scaled)^2)/nrow(testing_Data)
MSE.neuralnetModel
plot(real.values, pred_neuralnet.scaled, col='red',main='Real   vs  predicted',pch=18,cex=0.7)
abline(0,1,lwd=2)
legend('bottomright',legend='NN',pch=18,col='red',  bty='n')
```